# Provide the Views On Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

A) The number of meters read in the current month by each of the meter readers (this view should be able to be used at any time without having to be changed to accommodate the date).

Readings Table

```
    Name            Null     Type         
--------------- -------- ------------ 
READINGID       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4)  
READINGDATA              NUMBER(10)   
READINGDATE              DATE         
METERSERIALNO            VARCHAR2(10) 
EMPLOYEEID               VARCHAR2(10) 
LASTREADINGDATA          NUMBER(10)
```

Employee Table

```
    Name                 Null     Type         
-------------------- -------- ------------ 
EMPLOYEEID           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10) 
FIRSTNAME                     VARCHAR2(20) 
LASTNAME                      VARCHAR2(20) 
NUMBEROF_METERS_READ          NUMBER(10)
```

**My Answer**

```
create or replace view ViewA as
  select E.EmployeeID as Employee, E.FirstName, E.Numberof_Meters_Read, R.ReadingDate
   from   Employee E
   join
   Readings   R
   on (R.EmployeeID = E.EmlpoyeeID);
```

The Oracle is showing, 'Invalid Identifier'. Need help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aside from the typo, did you mean to have NUMBEROF_METERS_READ on employee? as that could only be a grand total, and not monthly total if so (unless you have some other process that's resetting it every month.

if you want to just do this by looking at readings..then create your view as this:

```
select e.employeeid as employee, e.firstname, count(r.readingdate) numberof_meters_read
   from employee e left outer join readings r
                                on (r.employeeid = e.employeeid)
                               and r.readingdate >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') 
                               and r.readingdate < add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), 1)
 group by e.employeeid, e.firstname;
```

or (if you want employees that havent done any owrk to appear as "0"):

```
 select e.employeeid as employee, e.firstname, count(*) numberof_meters_read
   from employee e join readings r
                     on (r.employeeid = e.employeeid)
 where r.readingdate >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
   and r.readingdate < add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), 1)
 group by e.employeeid, e.firstname;
```

Comment: I want to have the name of readers, number of readers, and months to be created on view but I don't know how to extract month from Date.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the last line to:

```
 on (R.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID)
```

(ie. `E.EmployeeID`, not `E.EmlpoyeeID`)